# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: weblogic, datasource

I am facing a class cast exception while doing lookup for datasource .we have recently migrated to weblogic 12c from weblogic 11. Below is the code via which I am looking up for Datasource .

```
        ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("my_data_source_name");
```

this code is giving class cast exception

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource

we have weblogic.jar in our class path .. i am not sure why it is returning the object of type WLEventContextImpl  instead of Datasource . Can someone suggest something?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and in my case I created a datasource without associate with a target, in the last page of datasource configuration you can see:

Select Targets:

Servers

[ ] AdminServer

After I check the AdminServer checkbox, I could use the datasource.